# Calculate range for any n-Bit long extended floating point

Tags: binary, floating-point, ieee-754

I am trying to imagine an 80-bit extended precision form with a 1 bit sign, 16-bit exponent,and 63-bit fraction excluding the implied 1 before the binary point. I know that to calculate the bias for any bit sized exponent, we just need to perform a simple operation; 2^(k-1) – 1, where k is the number of bits in the exponent. In this case we have a 16 bit exponent. So our the would bi like this,

```
Bias =  2^(k-1) – 1 ;  2^(16-1) – 1

Bias = 32 767
```

However, how should I calculate the range?

Comment: You are aware that this doesn't match the common 80-bit extended precision x87 format (which has 1 sign bit, 15 exponent bits, and 64 significand bits, and unlike the other IEEE 754 formats does *not* have a hidden 1-bit)?

Comment: I know, that is why I am asking.

Comment: Are you treating the all-bits-one exponent field as a normal exponent, or as reserved for infinities and NaNs? Are you allowing subnormal numbers?

Comment: Just normal exponent. Only difference is that is 16 bit long instead of 15.